# Transferring Minecraft PE from iPad to iPad mini

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to transfer Minecraft PE from my iPad to my daughters iPad Mini. I downloaded iexplorer and located the Minecraft worlds folder, but when I try and drag the worlds to my desktop (Windows Computer) it says Internet Explorer has quit working. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try iFunBox. It is useful. I have done stuff like that many times successfully with it.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer info from any two apple electronics, you will need to have iTunes on a computer. I have done this multiple times in the past as I got newer electronics and have recently done so with a school issued computer.

The easiest way to transfer a save file is to plug the charging cord from the iPad into a computer with iTunes downloaded (you can get it from the apple website) and syncing the info from the first electronic to it. Then, unplug the first electronic and replace it with the second and sync the info on to it.